# Installed package not showing in menu

Tags: linux, linux-mint, software-installation, package-management, synaptic

LINUX MINT 18.3

I have just installed Fgallery through software center of Linux Mint. But the app doesn't show in the menu.

[image: Screen shot from Synaptic package manager]

Answer (score 0):

`fgallery` is a command-line application. As such, it's designed to be executed from a terminal. It does have a *viewer*, but that's really an HTML/JavaScript app used to view the sites generated by the command-line tool.

In short, it doesn't make sense to create a `.desktop` file to add `fgallery` to the menu, because executing `fgallery` that way wouldn't accomplish anything.